# I want to skip showing the message when calling Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync() method

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm coding an Outlook Add-in.

I want to show a dialog message by using `displayDialogAsync()`.

But when I use the method, the confirmation message is shown, before displaying a dialog (I attached a screenshot).

Are there any solutions for skipping this message?

[image: screen shot : the message when a code calls displayDialogAsync()]

・reference

https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

```
    function openWindow()
    {
        var startAddress = 'https://localhost:44303/AppCompose/Sample/Sample.html';
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(startAddress);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is necessary to prevent pop-up blockers. So no, there is no way to skip it if you use pop-up mode. However, if your page supports iframing you can pass the displayAsIframe=true parameter (see [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync)); this mode doesn't show the extra confirmation because it is displayed as a floating div with an Iframe (as opposed to a new window).

Important: I see you are using the API in Office Online. Please be aware that we have not yet officially updated our documentation and samples to state that it's supported so you might see some bumps along the way. I expect everything will be in place by early next year.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook Web Access, use `window.open()` instead of the Dialog API. This will allow you to launch a child window without displaying this dialog. There are some caveats, though:

1. The URL of the window being launched must belong to the same domain as your add-in. Otherwise, you may see a popup blocked warning.
2. Firefox will show a popup blocked warning if `window.open()` is not called as a direct result of a user action. If your add-in's users may be using Firefox, just make sure that when launching a new window, that you're doing it directly within an `onClick` handler or something, not via a `Promise` or an async callback.

In Outlook desktop apps, the Dialog API works as expected, and in fact, using `window.open()` will always trigger a popup blocked warning.

Our add-in has logic similar to the following:

```
function launchDialog(url) {
  if (/WebApp/.test(Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName)) {
    window.open(url);
  } else {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!